# Do we have a setup task concept in hadoop streaming like we have in MapRed java?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, rscript

I am writing my mapper and reducer in R script . Here i am trying to read one file in the Rscript Mapper . Is there a way i can configure my streaming map red so that it only read this file single time not for each maptask . I understand for hadoop java the concept can be achieved via overriding setup task in mapper object.

Answer (score 0):

I found one link                                                                         http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/200906.mbox/%3C49efc3330906012210o191d426bqc3558b6420171e38@mail.gmail.com%3E

which actually states the same answer . I am adding this for other guy who might need this answer. Thanks

Comment: @michaeltang   My understanding with the link above is to put your setup logic before looping logic And you are done so the answer is yes. anything else you want to point ?